# jQuery use click function on dynamicly created button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a big "click" function in jQuery with a lot of code like this:

```
$(".Line1").click(function () {
    ...
}
```

I am creating new buttons dynamically which means that the "click" function doesn't trigger. Now I know that I could add a function like this in order to get it working:

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function () {
    ...
});
```

The problem is that my code in the normal click function is too long so I can't just copy and paste it into the new function, it would be way too confusing.

Is there a way where I can link it back up with the old click function?
Or can you think of anything else?

Comment: If you have to repeat whole actions which has been performed on first button click, then simply move that code in a function and then refer that function in each button's click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery +1.7 [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('body').on('click', '#myButton', function () {
    ...
});
```

Other versions (+1.4.2) [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('body').delegate('#myButton', 'click', function () {
    ...
});
```

More info: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can either trigger the first click as such

```
$(".Line1").click()
```

Or better move your large piece of code into a function so you can run it from the second click.